# MapStruct : Setting value of now while mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, mapstruct

I am trying to set a DateTime field in my mapped classes using MapStruct, but could not see any example.

So, can I set a DateTime or Instant field value as `now()` while mapping from DTO to Entity? How can I do this? I tried something below:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", imports = {Instant.class})
public interface DemoMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "created", target = "created", defaultValue = Instant.now())
    Employee toEntity(EmployeeDto source);

    EmployeeDto toDto(Employee destination);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defaultExpression` in your mapping. It expects a string as an argument, with the following format:

```
"java(expression)"
```

Where `expression` is the expression you're looking for, so in your case

```
@Mapping(source = "created", target = "created", defaultExpression = "java(java.time.Instant.now())")
```

Notice that I used the fully qualified name for the `Instant` class, since `defaultExpression` can't know where `Instant` is (or at least it can't assume you want the one from the standard library), so it can't import it in the file it generates.